# expresso store modifier

Tags: expressionengine, custom-fields, modifiers, expresso-store

I am working on a shop for a florist. The bouquets sometimes come in more than one size. I would like to have the different sizes available in a dropdown menu (i.e. regular = £30, medium = £50, large = £70). I would like to set this field up as a custom field rather than a modifier as it applies to almost every bouquet (but not all), and is kind of a pain for my client to have to add themselves into the product entry form (leaves too much margin for error in wording/styling, too). I can set up the entries using a custom Matrix field, but how do I code the template so that Store reads the prices correctly when they're added to the shopping cart?

Thanks!

Comment: good question, but it would really help if you provided some of your code, or even.. what language you are using for the code....

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to override the price using matrix fields or similar. You have to enter the modifiers separately for each product (unless they are only "text modifiers, but those can't adjust the price as you need). We're looking into ways to support this (while still remaining secure and not allowing users to simply post their own price in the form).

It would be possible to do this using PHP. Someone has managed to do this already in the [bulk discount add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-bulk-discount) - this seems to use Matrix to store the values. I haven't had a chance to see how this was done, though if you wanted to code something to solve your problem that would be a good starting point.

Comment: OK, thanks Adrian. Hopefully this will somehow become a feature down the road. Leaving too much to the client is never a good idea :)